# comment mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, comments, elisp, multiline

I commonly program in languages that don't have any sort of block/multiline comment (e.g. `python` [`#`] and `fortran` [`c` or `!`].).  Is there any way to define a minor mode in emacs that would allow me to enter multiline comments?  By that I mean, it would cause emacs to wrap text automatically after X lines (say 72) and automatically prepend a comment character (taken from the current major mode) to the beginning of each line?

Sorry if this is a pretty basic question -- my elisp skills are rudimentary at best.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
(setq fill-column 72)
(setq comment-auto-fill-only-comments t)
(auto-fill-mode t)
```

This will wrap the text automatically, only for the comments, and will insert the comment character everytime it does a line break.

I have this set up only for programming modes as follows:

```
(defun my-prog-mode-hook
  (setq fill-column 72)
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-auto-fill-only-comments) t)
  (auto-fill-mode t))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-prog-mode-hook)
```

This makes sure that if I turn auto-fill mode in a non programming mode such as AUCTeX all the text gets wrapped and not only the comments.

Comment: Hmm... I copied the above code into `.emacs` and it doesn't seem to do the wrapping for me.  (I'm using Aquamacs on OS-X if that makes a difference).

Comment: This code in emacs 24 with nothing loaded but these three lines (`emacs -q`) works. I do not know what Aquamacs does.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it on my linux machine when I get a little time and see if it works there.

Comment: No need to toggle auto fill. It should also work with M-q ( fill-paragraph )

Answer (score 0):

M-x ;

comments/uncomments the region

Comment: This does not answer the question. Text does not get wrapped.

Comment: Yes, I'm very aware of `M-x comment-region`.  I was more thinking about entering a minor mode which would allow comments to be wrapped natively.  (when typing comments like this, things can get all weird with emacs trying to help with syntax highlighting, etc).